# How do I correctly load a specific jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been given a script by my e-commerce provider that will allow me to dynamically change the stock levels based on the product option selected by the user from a simple select element.

While the code seems strait forward, it will not run properly. As I am fairly new to jQuery, I'm assuming this is due to me not properly initializing the script within my html. The code itself is a default code that my e-commerce provider hands out, but does not support it in any way.

Here is the script

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[  
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  if (variant) {
    if (variant.available) {
      // Selected a valid variant that is available.
      $('#add-to-cart').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled').val('Add to Cart').fadeTo(200,1);
    } else {
      // Variant is sold out.
      $('#add-to-cart').val('Sold Out').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').fadeTo(200,0.5);        
    }
    // Whether the variant is in stock or not, we can update the price and compare at price.
    if ( variant.compare_at_price > variant.price ) {
      $('#product_price').html('<span class="product-price on-sale">'+ Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "") +'</span>'+'&nbsp;<s class="product-compare-price">'+Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "")+ '</s>');
    } else {
      $('#product_price').html('<span class="product-price">'+ Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "") + '</span>' );
    }        
  } else {
    // variant doesn't exist.
    $('#add-to-cart').val('Unavailable').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').fadeTo(200,0.5);
  }
}
// initialize multi selector for product
jQuery(function($) {
  new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: , onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Any ideas on why this might not be working? You can see this script live on my site: 
http://www.yandasmusic.com/products/fender-american-standard-stratocaster?variant=1178632565

EDIT:
Upon further inspection, I have found a second piece of code that also calls up the product option selection box. I can tell that this code also serves the function of changing the currently shown product image based on the current option selected:

```
<script>
  var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
    if (variant && variant.available) {
      jQuery('#add-to-cart').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled'); // remove unavailable class from add-to-cart button, and re-enable button
      if(variant.price < variant.compare_at_price){
        jQuery('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span><span class="money compare-at-price">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span>');
      } else {
        jQuery('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span>');
      }
    } else {
      jQuery('#add-to-cart').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // set add-to-cart button to unavailable class and disable button
      var message = variant ? "Sold Out" : "Unavailable";
      jQuery('#product_price .price').text(message);
    }

//     if (variant && variant.featured_image) {
//         var originalImage = $(".zoomWrapper img");
//         var newImage = variant.featured_image;
//         var element = originalImage[0];
//         Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImage, element, function (newImageSizedSrc, newImage, element) {
//             $(element).parents('a').attr('href', newImageSizedSrc);
//             $(element).attr('src', newImageSizedSrc);
//         });
//     };

    if (variant && variant.featured_image) {
        var originalImage = $("#elevatezoom_big");
        var newImage = variant.featured_image;
        var element = originalImage[0];
        Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImage, element, function (newImageSizedSrc, newImage, element) {
            $(element).attr('src', newImageSizedSrc);

            $("#elevatezoom_gallery a").each(function(){
                if ( $(this).attr('data-zoom-image') == newImageSizedSrc ) {
                    $(this).trigger('click')
                };
            });
        });
    };

  };

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback, enableHistoryState: true });

    // Add label if only one product option and it isn't 'Title'.
    {% if product.options.size == 1 and product.options.first != 'Title' %}
      $('.selector-wrapper:eq(0)').prepend('<label>{{ product.options.first }}</label>');
    {% endif %}

    // Auto-select first available variant on page load.
    {% assign found_one_in_stock = false %}
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      {% if variant.available and found_one_in_stock == false %}
        {% assign found_one_in_stock = true %}
        {% for option in product.options %}
        $('.single-option-selector:eq({{ forloop.index0 }})').val({{ variant.options[forloop.index0] | json }}).trigger('change');
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

  });
</script>
```

If I run both scripts, the page shows two select boxes for the product options. Is it possible to combine them?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ /* new Shopify ... */  });`

Comment: Thanks for the replay Aivan. I added the above code into the /* new Shopfiy */ section, but it would seem the script is still not executing.

Comment: Not sure, im new to jQuery to but check `val('Sold Out')` Are you able to use a space like that? It might read it as two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You have a JavaScript error on your page because of this line of code:

```
new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: , onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
```

According to this reference document: https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/advanced-navigation/linked-product-options, that line of code should actually look like this:

```
new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
```

Comment: Excellent catch trevor. I have edited my question above with my findings based on your answer.